# ftp server in passive mode at private subnetwork

Tags: iptables, ftp, gateway, private-ip

I have following configuration:

FTP client (public_IP1) => internet => Firewall(Public_IP2) => FTP server (`10.10.12.171`)

I have following iptables rules at `Firewall`:

```
DNAT        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0      Public_IP2  tcp dpt:21 to:10.10.12.171
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.0.0.0/8     0.0.0.0/0
```

I have also `nf_conntrack_ftp` loaded at `Firewall`

```
nf_conntrack_ftp       13057  0 
nf_conntrack           79944  6 nf_conntrack_ftp,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_nat,iptable_nat,vzcpt,vzrst
```

In active mode everything works perfect. In passive mode I have following error (at client):

```
ftp> passive
Passive mode on.
ftp> dir
227 Entering Passive Mode (10,10,12,171,86,26)
ftp: connect: No route to host
```

I guess client tends to connect to my private IP (`10.10.12.171`). How to change it?

Comment: Try routing port 20 as well?

Comment: No, as far as i know port 20 is used only for active ftp connection

Comment: Active VS Passive is less about what ports are used and more about who activates the session. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699145/what-is-the-difference-between-active-and-passive-ftp

Comment: Sounds like you found your solution though so whoops

Comment: yes, but port 20 is used ONLY in active mode for data transferring. In passive mode is used some random high-numbered port

Comment: You're right actually, my apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ftp server should be configured, as it's behind NAT. You didn't say what ftp server software you are using, so i will provide required config directive example for proFTPd:

```
# If your host was NATted, this option is useful in order to
# allow passive tranfers to work. You have to use your public
# address and opening the passive ports used on your firewall as well.
MasqueradeAddress       Public_IP2
```

Comment: yes, thanks. That is a solution. I have pure-ftp and relevant configuration stands in /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/ForcePassiveIP.

echo Public_IP2 >  /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/ForcePassiveIP.

But I face another problem. I need to forward also ports for passive connections (listed in /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/PassivePortRange). In my situation I have a lot of FTP servers (they are VZ Containers in fact). So, i need N(containers)*M(simultaneous users per container) IPTable rules.
Moreover configurations on each server must be different.
Maybe exists simpler way to handle this problem?

Comment: I suggest to use unique passive ports range on ftp servers, and in addition, on gateway : -A FORWARD -i EXTIF -o INTIF -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT. Replace  EXTIF and INTIF with yours.

Comment: Yes, thanks (that what i called "configuration on each server must be different"). Maybe exist some masquerading for ports? I will look for solution and report. Дяк.

Answer (score 0):

There exist two solutions:

1. As mention @andrii-kupchanko you can change ftp server configuration.  This changes force server to send external IP (`Public_IP2`) to client as IP for passive backward-connection. Drawback is necessity of forwarding passive connection back to private subnet resident FTP-server (via iptables) and statically binding ports used by passive connections
2. You just need two modules `nf_conntrack_ftp` and `nf_nat_ftp`. Lack of second module is why passive connection to server behind gateway didn't work.